# How to align these objects in a function mapping

Tags: horizontal-alignment, arrays, alignment

I'm trying to write a function mapping between three sets. I'd like to keep the alignment of the first "array" environment in the second one, because I'd like the tips and the tails of the arrows in the last two rows to be aligned with those of the previous arrows. Similarly, the variables "I" and "h" should touch the red lines I've drawn in this screenshot:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\xmapsfrom}[2][]{%
    \ext@arrow3095\leftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}\mapsfromchar
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \[
  \begin{array}{c}
   \begin{array}{ccccc}
    \{\text{Ideali massimali di $\mathcal{A}$}\} & \longleftrightarrow & \{\text{Ultrafiltri di $\mathcal{A}$}\} & \longleftrightarrow & S(\mathcal{A}) \\
    I & \longmapsto & \{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in I\} && \\
    \{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in F\} & \longmapsfrom & F & \longmapsto & h_F \\
    && \{x \in A \colon h(x) = 1\} & \longmapsfrom & h
   \end{array} \\
   \begin{array}{ccc}
    I & \xmapsto{\hphantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}} & h_I \\
    \{x \in A \colon h(x) = 0\} & \xmapsfrom{\hphantom{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}} & h
   \end{array}
  \end{array}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single `array` environment and place the long arrows the three central columns using in `\multicolumn`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\xmapsfrom}[2][]{%
    \ext@arrow3095\leftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}\mapsfromchar
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
   \begin{array}{ccccc}
    \{\text{Ideali massimali di $\mathcal{A}$}\} & \longleftrightarrow & \{\text{Ultrafiltri di $\mathcal{A}$}\} & \longleftrightarrow & S(\mathcal{A}) \\
    I & \longmapsto & \{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in I\} && \\
    \{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in F\} & \longmapsfrom & F & \longmapsto & h_F \\
    && \{x \in A \colon h(x) = 1\} & \longmapsfrom & h \\
    I & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\xmapsto{\hspace{12.5em}}} & h_I \\
    \{x \in A \colon h(x) = 0\} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\xmapsfrom{\hspace{12.5em}}} & h
   \end{array}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Since there is no use for the `array` environment with the single `c` column in which the actual `array` is placed, I removed it. Also, as suggested by @Davislor in the comments, I changed both the `\hphantom{aa...aa}` to `\hspace{12.5em}`.

Comment: Would a length in `em` (which scales to the horizontal metrics of the font) be a little more elegant than a `\hphantom{aaa...}`?

Answer (score 1):

A  solution with `alignat*` and `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\makeatletter
 \newcommand{\xmapsfrom}[2][]{%
 \ext@arrow3095\leftarrowfill@{#1}{#2}\mapsfromchar
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{3}
  \eqmathbox[S]{\{\text{Ideali massimali di }\mathcal{A}\}} & \longleftrightarrow \eqmathbox[M]{\{\text{Ultrafiltri di $\mathcal{A}$}\}} \longleftrightarrow{} && \eqmathbox[D]{S(\mathcal{A})} \\
  \eqmathbox[S]{ I} & \xmapsto{\phantom{\longleftrightarrow}} \eqmathbox[M]{\{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in I\}} && \\
   \eqmathbox[S]{ \{x \in A \colon x^\mathbf{c} \in F\}} & \xmapsfrom{\phantom{\longleftrightarrow}} \eqmathbox[M]{F} \xmapsto{\phantom{\longleftrightarrow}} & & \eqmathbox[D]{h_F} \\
  &\phantom{{}\longleftrightarrow{}}\eqmathbox[M]{\{x \in A \colon h(x) = 1\}}\xmapsfrom{\phantom{\longleftrightarrow}} && \eqmathbox[D]{h} \\
    \eqmathbox[S]{I} & \xmapsto{\hphantom{\displaystyle{\longleftrightarrow}\eqmathbox[M]{}{\longleftrightarrow}}} & & \eqmathbox[D]{h_I} \\
    \eqmathbox[S]{\{x \in A \colon h(x) = 0\}} & \xmapsfrom{\hphantom{\displaystyle{\longleftrightarrow}\eqmathbox[M]{}{\longleftrightarrow}}} & & \eqmathbox[D]{h}
 \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]